# Fast celllarray by matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, vectorization, cell-array

I have a long (~7000) cellarray containing each a 3x3 matrix. I would like to premultiply and post-multiply each of those matrices by the same 3-dimensional vector a. This operation could be expressed as:

```
[a1 a2 a3]'*M*[a1 a2 a3] ,
```

where `a = [a1 a2 a3]`

My question is: How can I implement this in a fast way? I have tried with a simple for loop and it results to be much faster than using `cellfun` after reshaping the vector a in as many 3x3 matrices we have and converting it to a cell array. Any idea?

EDIT: maybe the cell array containing the 3x3 matrices could be expressed in another form so it is possible to compute the operation in a fully vectorized way.

Comment: You don't have a choice but to loop over each cell array... that's just the nature of how cell arrays are.  Also, doing the simple `for` loop is probably the fastest that you're going to get it.  However, do you have the option of **collecting** all 7000 matrices?  If you do, you can collect all of them and compute the multiplication in one step.

Comment: the problem is that the 'a' vector changes after each iteration of the code....

Comment: OK, but are you able to collect all of the 7000 matrices and 7000 `a` vectors before hand?

Comment: Yes. The 7000 matrices are constants.  The vector, as I said, changes after each iteration.

Comment: Do you know how `a` changes before hand, or will you only know its contents once you start the loop each time?

Comment: Yes, I only know its new value at the beginning of the iteration.

Comment: If that's the case, then the loop is and will be your only option.  If you can't reliably predict what `a` is, then it isn't really a question of whether you can compute the quadratic product more efficiently, but it's a matter of collecting `a`.  Doing the operation once you know the `a` is actually not complicated... but because you don't know this, then you can't vectorize.

Comment: ok, thanks. And what about expressing those matrices in a  different way (maybe losing the matricial structure ) and get rid off the cellarray? or split the M*a process in different smaller task that can be done in a vectorised way?

Comment: You could represent the matrix structure as `3 x 3 x 7000` 3D matrix where each slice is a 3D matrix.  You could then perform the quadratic product by `[a1 a2 a3]*M(:,:,idx)*[a1; a2; a3]` where `idx` is your loop counter.  The fact that you don't know what `a` is before hand makes vectorization difficult.

Comment: I meant each slice is a 2D matrix sorry.